# What are the values for the 'country' field in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have a feeling Windows expects 'country' to be an integer, with 0 meaning 'US'. If that's the case, what's the mapping between integers and ISO 2-letter country codes?active

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this link here:

[ISO 3166 Country Codes](http://userpage.chemie.fu-berlin.de/diverse/doc/ISO_3166.html)

Seems to be standard ISO 3166 country codes used in several places.

Same result from this post here: Active Directory and .NET

Point 5 reads:

> *5. Set user's country*
>
> *To set the country property for a user
>   was one of the tasks that took me some
>   time to figure out. After some hours
>   of research I realized that you need
>   to know the **ISO 3166 Codes** for
>   countries and set three properties to
>   define a user's country: c, co, and
>   countryCode.*

Best overview that includes the elusive ISO 3166 **numeric codes** can be found on [Wikipedia - of course](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_numeric)! (at ISO itself, you can't seem to get those lists for free - you have to pay for the privilege....)

Answer (score 9):

There are three different properties that must be set in Active Directory. Each is designated in the [ISO 3166 standard](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes.htm). The ISO website has a [search tool](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#search) that you can use to find the official codes. Select *Country codes* and hit search, then click on *Officially assigned...* on the left.

- [`c`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) — 2 digit abbreviation (e.g. **US**)

  > The country/region in the address of the user. The country/region is represented as a 2-character code based on ISO-3166.
- [`co`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) — Country name (e.g. **United States**). Microsoft got really detailed on their description for this one.

  > The country/region in which the user is located.
- [`countryCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) — Numeric Id (e.g. **840**)

  > Specifies the country/region code for the user's language of choice. This value is not used by Windows 2000.

  Note: If you want to clear the country field, then you need to set this value to `0`. You cannot set it to `null` or `String.Empty`. It will throw a `DirectoryServicesCOMException` stating "The server is unwilling to process the request" when you call `CommitChanges()` if you try to set it to anything other than an `int`.

  ```
  DirectoryEntry.Properties["countryCode"].Value = 0;
  ```

Answer (score 7):

There's two country properties, `countryCode` and `c`, both are ISO 3166 values. The former is a number and the latter a string (ISO 3166 A2).

See [ISO 3166](http://userpage.chemie.fu-berlin.de/diverse/doc/ISO_3166.html).

Also, there's the `co` property which is the name of country.